# What is the painting in Gregory House's kitchen?

Tags: analysis, house

The screenshot below shows the back wall in Gregory House's kitchen.

[image: House's kitchen painting]

What is that painting and who is the original author/painter?

It might be artwork specifically created for the show, but I'm pretty sure, it is a reproduction of an existing painting. Some time ago I read it somewhere (or heard in a documentary) but I can't seem to find it again. I also tried Google's reverse image search with no success.

Comment: Provide info about episode.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but found a few links that might help you - [This](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/good-questions-paint-color-use-38878) lead me to this https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/175499716704474301/ - which may show the painting with some more info

Comment: Also, not sure if those are letters? Top row g/q? I? n? Bottom ? r? l/i?

Comment: @Rahul the painting is visible in all shots of House's kitchen from season 2 onward. As far as I know it has not been changed during the course of the show.

Comment: @Longshanks Thanks, but I found those links, too. I did quite some research before I posted here - without any luck.

Comment: [Cassells noted that the apartment is really the work of Katie Jacobs. Dark and masculine, “it’s House’s nest: his sanctuary.” However, many of the objects d’arte that decorate the apartment are Hugh Laurie’s doing.](https://blogcritics.org/behind-the-scenes-with-house-md/)

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks for this very interesting article, that led me to [another yet unseen page](http://zeppomarx.livejournal.com/28230.html), but it still doesn't identify any of the paintings/pictures.

Comment: If you find a better quality screenshot, you could crop the painting, choose a better white balance, sharpen it and upload it to images.google.com

Comment: @EricDuminil I did exactly that without any results.

Comment: Shoot. I tried it too but it didn't work either.